# Trying to save workbook to a folder specified by the user

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I am trying to make a macro that saves a report to a specific folder. Our folders get generated every day like `C://Report_Type/2017/11/10` (where `/10` is the folder I'd want to save the file to).

The code I have prompts the user to provide the date in order to have the folder located, and then it saves the file according to a specified name.

However when I run the macro it saves the file in the `C://Report_Type/2017/11` root folder ignoring the day based on userinput. Could someone help where I got it wrong?

It's a bit complicated to explain, but if you check the code then it makes sense.

```
Sub PSSaveFile()
    Dim myVal2 As Variant
    Dim myDate As String
    Dim mFilePath As String

    myVal2 = InputBox("Please enter today's date in mm\dd format")
    myDate = Date - 1
    mFilePath = "\\sample\sample_emea\sec_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\sample_security_app\2017\" & myVal2

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=mFilePath & "SampleLogs-" & myDate & "-12352_checked"
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: It is just a Typo: There is just a `\ ` missing before `SampleLogs` I think: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=mFilePath & "\SampleLogs-" & myDate & "-12352_checked"`. So there must be a backslash between the path and the filename.

Comment: Well hot damn, such a tiny mistake makes such a huge difference. Thank you very much for pointing that out! I'd have never figured it out. Can you write it down as an answer so I can give you an upvote?

Comment: `myDate = Date - 1` will also give you error. Also you are not specifying file extension and file format number

Comment: it saves it as a plain workbook (prompting the user if she wants to save it as a macro free workbook), 'myDate = Date-1' works on my end perfectly, there is no problem with the file name.

Comment: `"\SampleLogs-" & date - 1 & "-12352_checked"` gives you `\SampleLogs-28/11/2017-12352_checked` which will create problems becuase of "/"

Comment: It automatically replaces the `"\"` with `"-"` for some odd reason, like if I run the code it saves the file with the following name `SampleLogs-2017-11-28-12352_checked`

Comment: No it doesn't automatically replace. your regional setting is as such...

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know that. So would it be fine as is then or should I weave in the `Replace` function?

Comment: Use the Replace. See the edit in my post. Since you are using Inputbox, I ameded the code slightly. You may have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why make it so complicated? I mean why ask for date when you can get that automatically?

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Sub PSSaveFile()
    Dim FilePath_A As String, FilePath_B As String, FilePath_C As String
    Dim sFile As String

    FilePath_A = "\\sample\sample_emea\sec_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\sample_security_app\2017\"
    FilePath_B = Format(Date, "mm\dd")
    FilePath_C = "\SampleLogs-" & Replace(Date - 1, "/", "-") & "-12352_checked.xlsx"

    sFile = FilePath_A & FilePath_B & FilePath_C

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFile, 51
End Sub
```

**Few things**

1. While naming files avoid the use of special characters like `\ / : * ? " < > |` and hence we use `Replace(Date - 1, "/", "-")` in the above code
2. Mention the file extention and file format number
3. Break your code in easy to understand "parts". makes it easier to understand and manage the code.

> Yeah this one is a simpler approach, unfortunately the user who'll be using the macro often checks backlogs so the date she's reviewing isn't always today's or yesterday's date hence the userinput function – Rhyfelwr 14 mins ago

Since you are using InputBox you may want to use this

```
Sub PSSaveFile()
    Dim FilePath_A As String, FilePath_B As String, FilePath_C As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Ret = InputBox("Please enter date in mm\dd format")

    If Ret = "" Then Exit Sub

    FilePath_A = "\\sample\sample_emea\sec_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\sample_security_app\2017\"
    FilePath_B = Ret

    '~~> Check if the folder path exists
    If FileFolderExists(FilePath_A & FilePath_B) Then
        FilePath_C = "\SampleLogs-" & Replace(Date - 1, "/", "-") & "-12352_checked.xlsx"

        sFile = FilePath_A & FilePath_B & FilePath_C

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFile, 51
    Else
        MsgBox "The folder path " & FilePath_A & FilePath_B & " doesn't exist"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah this one is a simpler approach, unfortunately the user who'll be using the macro often checks backlogs so the date she's reviewing isn't always today's or yesterday's date hence the userinput function

Comment: ok in that case modify the `FilePath_B`. But notice what i commented under your question

Comment: @Peh: True that.. Fixed :)